# JQUERY Show overlay when button click work only first time. What's wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Why my overlay 'p' **(bg purple with yellow text)** is showing only once after button clicked, even if I have toggle the function?

Have a look to my codepen to test the issue:

**https://codepen.io/cat999/project/editor/AEeEdg**

```
    $('.animate-this').click(function() {
                $('p').slideToggle("fast");
        });
```

Easy way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The `.animate-this` element gets hidden when the `<p>` is visible.
You can add the same functionality to the `<p>`, then it will work.

```
$('.animate-this, p').click(function() {
    $('p').slideToggle("fast");
});
```

However, I would recommend not biding an event to a tag, but to a class.
So you can just add the class `.animate-this` to the `<p>` tag and it will work too, like this:

```
<p class="animate-this">If you click i need to show up again!</p>
```

Comment: Thanks @Elron but when I re-clicked on the button the second time I still have the same issue and my  `p` is still not visible. Could you tested on my codepen?

Comment: Sure, but its Read Only. change it and I will be happy to assist.

Comment: how we could do it? unfortunately I could not change it in codepen probably. You could see my code anyway right? I have change the way you suggested me but still not work ```$('.animate-this, p').click(function() {
    $('p').slideToggle("fast");
});```   have a look

Comment: I could send you a .zip files?

Comment: are you still here  ;) ?

Comment: just replace to this line: <p class="animate-this">If you click i need to show up again!</p>

Comment: use "this" instead of "'p'", like this: $('.animate-this, p').click(function() { $(this).slideToggle("fast"); });

Comment: I still can see it only once when clicked, just the first time..have a look. I replace the line you suggested me.. have a look (https://codepen.io/cat999/project/editor/AEeEdg)

Comment: It works. clicking on "home page" opens the slide, clicking on the purple background or text closes the slide. Isn't it how it should work?

Comment: Should be:  clicking on "home page" opens the slide, have the purple background or text closes the slide... but when i click again the pruple background is missing..

Comment: It worked just a minute ago. Do what you did and it should work.

Comment: Thanks anyway Elron but did not worked... Is still visible only the first time. Now all your suggestion are in  exept for $('.animate-this, p').click(function() { $(this).slideToggle("fast"); }); –  that is creating a different animation

Comment: Right, sorry, $(this) is not what you need. I see that it works: https://i.imgur.com/sxcMrwu.gif

Comment: here what i got unfortunately. I'm running on chrome https://pasteboard.co/J9J95Z5.gif .  I try to not clicked immediately to simulate all the animation transition from page to page

Comment: Of course, it will redirect to a different page since you are clicking a link. Do you want to disable that link?

Comment: if so, try changing href attribute to this: `<a href="javascript:return false">`. you can read more about it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/event-preventdefault-vs-return-false